# From where can I download old Java 6 Update 6?

Tags: windows-7, java

I am trying to install Cisco SDM and it only works with Java 6 Update 6, but I am not able to find where to download it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need such an old version you can get it from the Java Archive Page:

[Archive: Download Java Platform Standard Edition (Java SE) 6 Update 6](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/j2se/6u6/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Oracle Java Archive](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html).

More specifically: [Java SE Runtime Environment 6u6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jre-6u6-oth-JPR)

Comment: You are right, there is not more to answer the question than this. You could have at least linked to the exact download though. Just a tip: ranting about the deletion won't make it better.